# How to update ng-style in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I have a `ng-style` inside of `ng-repeat`. The problem is the `ng-style` value is updated after a change but the actual style does not change.

```
<tr class="row" ng-repeat="(hourIndex, hour) in day track by $index">
  <td class="cell"
      ng-style="{ 'background-color': '{{ switchBackgroundColor(hour) }}' }">
    {{ hour }}%
  </td>
</tr>
```

As stated above once the day and in turn hour changes, the `ng-style` is updated. This update is not reflected in the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `{{...}}` for your css, it's already within angular since you're using ng-style.

```
<tr class="row" ng-repeat="(hourIndex, hour) in day track by $index">
    <td class="cell" ng-style="{ 'background-color': switchBackgroundColor(hour) }">
        {{ hour }}%
    </td>
</tr>
```